# jqgrid and lightning aura components integration?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, aura

I am looking for the examples for jqgrid with salesforce lightning. How to inject URL into jqgrid javascript??

so far i have managed to pull data from salesforce apex component but for supporting inline-edit i need to use **URL** that will call **apex component's** **method with @RemoteAction**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log(">>>1");
    //--
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        if (a.getState() === "SUCCESS") {
            result = a.getReturnValue();
            console.log(result);
            //---=
            var editActionOptions = {
                keys: true,
                url:null,
                oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
                    console.log("row with rowid=" + rowid + " is editing.");
                },
                aftersavefunc: function (rowid, response, options) {
                    console.log("row with rowid=" + rowid + " is successfuly modified.");
                }
            };
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                editurl: 'clientArray',
                datatype: "local",
                data:result,
                colModel: [
                    {
                        label: "Edit Actions",
                        name: "actions",
                        width: 100,
                        formatter: "actions",
                        formatoptions: {
                            keys: true,
                            editOptions: {},
                            addOptions: {},
                            delOptions: {}
                        }       
                    },
                    {
                        labe: 'ID',
                        name: 'empid',
                        width: 75
                    },
                    {
                        label : 'Name',
                        name: 'Name',
                        width: 140,
                        editable: true // must set editable to true if you want to make the field editable
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'dob',
                        name: 'dob',
                        width: 100,
                        editable: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'dln',
                        name: 'dln',
                        width: 120,
                        editable: true
                    }
                ],
                sortname: 'empid',
                loadonce: true,
                onSelectRow: editRow,
                onSave:onSaveRow,
                editParams: editActionOptions,
                width: 780,
                height: 400,
                rowNum: 150,
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
            });               

            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        } else if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {
            $A.log("Errors", a.getError());
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all Salesforce strongly recommends not to use third party libraries for building functionalities using aura components.

If you still want to pursue this option.

ltng:require tag to load the library from a static resource and use the afterscriptloaded attribute to call a helper function to bind jqgrid to your html dom

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_ltng_require.htm

```
    styles="{!$Resource.SLDSv1 + '/assets/styles/lightning-design-system-ltng.css'}"

    scripts="{!$Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js'}"

    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
```

scriptsLoaded function will contain the code to bind jqgrid tables to dom.

Comment: sorry about confusion, i am aware of javascript static urls. I need to reference Component (Apex).

Comment: can you clarify what you mean when you say you want to reference component

Comment: jqrid needs url to action on the server side which in case of salesforce it is apex component having method @RemoteAction